Angular content projection when wrapping another component
I'm using a third-party component repeatedly in my application. To simplify usage, I would like to wrap it in a custom component, which sets a few default attributes.
The problem with this is, that the 3rd party component uses different ng-content select slots,  which I am not able to pass through my wrapper to the 3rd party component. Is it somehow possible to work around this problem?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular11-contentprojection-hn4cdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h4>Direct usage of ThirdPartyCard</h4>
    <third-party-card>
      <span head>This is the head.... I guess</span>
      <span body>This is just a nonsense text</span>
      Even more
    </third-party-card>

    <hr />

    <h4>Wrapped usage of ThirdPartyCard</h4>
    <app-wrapper-card>
      <span head>This is the head.... I guess</span>
      <span body>This is just a nonsense text</span>
      Even more
    </app-wrapper-card>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wrapper-card',
  template: `
    <third-party-card someattribute=defaultvalue1 someattribute2=defaultvalue2>
      <ng-content />
    </third-party-card>
  `,
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'third-party-card',
  template: `
    <div>Head: <ng-content select="[head]" /></div>
    <div>Body: <ng-content select="[body]" /></div>
    <div>Rest: <ng-content /></div>
  `,
})
export class ThirdPartyCardComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

results in


Your wrapper component should wrap its content slots with the 3rd party. This should do what you want.
Your wrapper:
<div>
   <ng-container thirdPartyHead>
      <ng-content select="[yourHead]"></ng-content>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container thirdPartyBody>
      <ng-content select="[yourBody]"></ng-content>
   </ng-container>
</div>


I see. Do you know if there is a more generic way? The problem is my example is a bit simplified. The real selectors are not that short and unfortunatly out of my control. I would really like to not duplicate them if possible.

This wrapper component will ensure you never duplicate the third party attributes. I'm not sure I understand you, but if you use this wrapper component, you'll never have to interact directly with the third party control again.

Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to say that my custom component would have to provide/implement a full copy of all selects that the 3rd party component has. Which I really would like to avoid.

You would need to provide one ng-content area for each of the third party's controls you would want to specify. If there are some third party areas you don't need control over, you can leave those off or hardcode them (no ng-content).

I'm not aware of any Angular feature that lets you specify a 3rd party components ng-content areas without explicitly calling out those attributes in your template. I don't think you can get around that.
